# Why the down votes?

Tags: support

I was asking a [fine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277239/elder-scrolls-online-architectural-differences) question and am getting down votes without explanation, please explain why?

Also why are the downvotes  reducing reputation by 2 and not 1 please also explain?

Comment: First of all, which question, and secondly, downvotes take 2 rep from the receiver and 1 from the giver.

Comment: Presumably OP is referring to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277239/elder-scrolls-online-architectural-differences) question.

Comment: Yes I am.      (Just filling this space in this needs to be changed)

Comment: @Dragonrage  "downvotes take 2 rep from the receiver and 1 from the giver. "  That's on answers.  On questions downvotes normally take 1 rep from the recipient and 0 rep from the voter.  Note that question upvotes also only change reputation half as much as on answers.

Comment: @Brythan good catch. I clearly had not met my daily allotment of coffee or something when I posted that. Completely forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5):

One probable reason is that it's extremely hard to understand what you're asking.  There are spelling mistakes everywhere, you're missing capitals all over the place, and your grammar needs some work as well.  People can (and generally do) downvote for those reasons, among others.  That's my guess as to why it's happening.

We expect users to show some effort when posting questions.  Clean up the spelling and grammar, and try to clarify what it is you're asking.  That will help immensely.

As a sidenote, users don't have to justify their downvotes.  Nobody commented, so the old standby is all you have to go on: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

Comment: I put effort in though

Comment: It doesn't really show; if there's that much still wrong with it, then you probably need to put in a bit more.

Comment: Oh and we all don't have access to a PC 24/7

Comment: If you can't touch up your post because it's not accessible, then I'd suggest you make sure get it right before posting it.  If you post something with spelling and grammar mistakes, downvotes are the norm.  You should expect them to happen.

Comment: Use either one, we're not picky.  As long as the words are spelled correctly, we're all good.

Comment: Ok, can we please stop the character rule on comments?

Comment: Nope.  That's there for a reason as well.  Comments aren't for being chatty.

Comment: Is this website just not for mmo's or is it just people on this site don't play 'complicated' games like eso?

Comment: @Cameron.C Yes, we answer questions about games besides Pokemon Go.

Answer (score 5):

Well your spelling doesn't help:

> all of tae differntt architecture

Neither does your grammar, capitilizations (i, proper nouns), missing words (i could work if they) etc.

I believe however that the main problem is that your question is very vague and open ended. You say you want "a guide to all of the different architectures" in the game.

Firstly this is very unclear as to what exactly you are looking for, add some specifics and more details. What kinds of differences are you looking for.

Secondly architecture is not an expertise of most people here.